# What programming language has the specific purpose of testing concurrent algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, parallel-processing, proof, proof-of-correctness

A colleague of mine has written a program that proves that some conditions will not be met after testing an algorithm running multiple concurrent threads trying to find a sequence that might trigger the unwanted condition. He used a computer language that was designed for this purpose, but I can't remember its name. What are the languages that serve this specific purpose?

Comment: I found the source code I was looking for
https://github.com/dgryski/modelchecking/blob/master/spin/ipc.pml, now I'm trying to google "pml" and "spin" to figure out how to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spin is a popular open-source software verification tool, used by
>   thousands of people worldwide. The tool can be used for the formal
>   verification of multi-threaded software applications. The tool was
>   developed at Bell Labs in the Unix group of the Computing Sciences
>   Research Center, starting in 1980. The software has been available
>   freely since 1991, and continues to evolve to keep pace with new
>   developments. In April 2002 the tool was awarded the ACM System
>   Software Award.

http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html